Insert operations in MariaDB causing deadlocks
I created the following table in MariaDB:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (
id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
uuid VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
CONSTRAINT unique_name UNIQUE (uuid)
); 

When I ran multiple threads simultaneously to insert into the table, a deadlock occurred.

msg:Error: 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

I am not sure why this is causing a deadlock.
Here is my test Python code:
import threading
import mysql.connector
import uuid
import time

db_config = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'database': 'device.db-0',
}

def insert_data(thread_id):
    time.sleep(10)
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
        sql = """
        INSERT INTO test_table (uuid)
        VALUES (%s)
        """
        cursor.execute(sql, (uuid,))
        connection.commit()
        print(f"Thread {thread_id}: Inserted uuid {uuid}")

    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print(f"Thread {thread_id}: Error: {err}")

    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

threads = []
for i in range(500):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=insert_data, args=(i,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print("All threads have finished.")

Mariadb Version:  10.11.5-MariaDB
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS

*** (1) TRANSACTION: TRANSACTION 1894, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting mysql tables in use 1, locked 1 LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1128,
3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1 MariaDB thread id 369, OS thread
handle 139691940092728, query id 1548 172.28.0.13 root Update INSERT
INTO test_table (uuid)
VALUES ('fa6fbd1c-a7df-4f28-a1f6-f980d7a12fac')
*** WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED: RECORD LOCKS space id 22 page no 4 n bits 88 index unique_name of table device.db-0.test_table
trx id 1894 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 75 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format;
info bits 0  0: len 8; hex 000000009a7a5f68; asc      z_h;;  1: len 8;
hex 000000000000017b; asc        {;;
*** CONFLICTING WITH: RECORD LOCKS space id 22 page no 4 n bits 88 index unique_name of table device.db-0.test_table trx id 1894
lock_mode X locks gap before rec Record lock, heap no 75 PHYSICAL
RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0  0: len 8; hex
000000009a7a5f68; asc      z_h;;  1: len 8; hex 000000000000017b; asc
{;;
RECORD LOCKS space id 22 page no 4 n bits 88 index unique_name of
table device.db-0.test_table trx id 1894 lock_mode X locks gap
before rec insert intention Record lock, heap no 75 PHYSICAL RECORD:
n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0  0: len 8; hex
000000009a7a5f68; asc      z_h;;  1: len 8; hex 000000000000017b; asc
{;;
RECORD LOCKS space id 22 page no 4 n bits 88 index unique_name of
table device.db-0.test_table trx id 1907 lock_mode X locks gap
before rec Record lock, heap no 75 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2;
compact format; info bits 0  0: len 8; hex 000000009a7a5f68; asc
z_h;;  1: len 8; hex 000000000000017b; asc        {;;
*** (2) TRANSACTION: TRANSACTION 1907, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting mysql tables in use 1, locked 1 LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1128,
2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1 MariaDB thread id 423, OS thread
handle 139691916532536, query id 1566 172.28.0.13 root Update INSERT
INTO test_table (uuid)
VALUES ('bcd28a18-2836-42fa-ad3d-42fd3dd3275c')
*** WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED: RECORD LOCKS space id 22 page no 4 n bits 88 index unique_name of table device.db-0.test_table
trx id 1907 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 75 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format;
info bits 0  0: len 8; hex 000000009a7a5f68; asc      z_h;;  1: len 8;
hex 000000000000017b; asc        {;;
*** CONFLICTING WITH: RECORD LOCKS space id 22 page no 4 n bits 88 index unique_name of table device.db-0.test_table trx id 1894
lock_mode X locks gap before rec Record lock, heap no 75 PHYSICAL
RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0  0: len 8; hex
000000009a7a5f68; asc      z_h;;  1: len 8; hex 000000000000017b; asc
{;;
RECORD LOCKS space id 22 page no 4 n bits 88 index unique_name of
table device.db-0.test_table trx id 1894 lock_mode X locks gap
before rec insert intention Record lock, heap no 75 PHYSICAL RECORD:
n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0  0: len 8; hex
000000009a7a5f68; asc      z_h;;  1: len 8; hex 000000000000017b; asc
{;;
RECORD LOCKS space id 22 page no 4 n bits 88 index unique_name of
table device.db-0.test_table trx id 1907 lock_mode X locks gap
before rec Record lock, heap no 75 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2;
compact format; info bits 0  0: len 8; hex 000000009a7a5f68; asc
z_h;;  1: len 8; hex 000000000000017b; asc        {;;
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)


with 600 threads you will automatically get an deadlock, as the mysql server can only handle one insert at a time

@nbk - Are you saying that 599 is safe?

@RickJames See his code he creates 600 threads and does only one insert per thread , multi threading can not be handled by most databases, this is why you allow only one thread to write with semaphores

For 600 single-row INSERTs I would not expect deadlocks, but I would expect  terrible inefficiency.  A single 600-row ("batch") INSERT will be more efficient and probably even faster (elapsed time).

I've often seen unexpected deadlocks on INSERT for a table that has both a primary key and a secondary UNIQUE constraint. Your table matches this description. It's as if the locks are not acquired atomically. The solution is to remove the secondary UNIQUE constraint, or use table-locking, or some external locking (not managed by MySQL) to force inserts to be executed serially.

You tagged the question both mysql and mariadb. Please be aware that these are not the same product. They are not fully compatible, and a solution for one may not be appropriate for the other. Be clear about which one you're using. Query SELECT VERSION(); and include the result of that query in your question.

Thank you for your suggestion. I have already included the database version.

Unfortunately, there is not enough information that would explain this behaviour. 600 simultaneous INSERTs is something MySQL should handle, albeit it will take time. I, actually, tested this and it works just fine.
What would be useful to see is the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G as a minimum. If performance schema is enabled, you can use it to extract data about locks and lock waits that may also shed some light on the problem. Then, with that data, you may be able to look what caused the deadlock. Right now it’s just guessing.

thank you, include the result of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
